# Exchange point and mark in Vim selection

Tags: vim, vi, spacemacs, evil-mode

I want to exchange point and mark in a selection of text using vanilla Vim.

Consider a code block with some comments immediately preceding the block.  Suppose I want to operate only on the code block.  I can select the paragraph with `vip`.  Doing this, however, places the cursor *at the bottom* of the paragraph.  Were I able to exchange where the cursor is with where the selection starts, I could then move down.

[image: <code>vip</code> <code>C-x C-x</code> <code>jj</code>]

Since I am an Evil user, I can just do `vip` `C-x C-x o` `jj`, where the middle sequence is `exchange-point-and-mark`.  How do I do it without Emacs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is command [`o` in visual mode, aka `v_o`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#v_o).

Comment: Reading `:h v_$` we learn we can move to any corner of the selection